# Performance measurement of Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to compare the performance between SparkSql on Parquet and Phoenix on HBase .
The query that I am executing has joins and aggregations
The way I am trying to check the Spark Sql on Parquet performance is by doing the following :

```
spark.time(sql("some sql").show)
```

My questions are :

1. Is that the right and easiest way to test the time required for
   Spark Sql executions
2. I am directly executing the phoenix queries
   in Spark Sql . Is there a way I can do some optimisations in it ?

Comment: Here a good post about it: https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-03-measuring-apache-spark-workload-metrics-performance-troubleshooting

Comment: df.show() pulls no more than 20 rows from the resultset. Depending on how expensive to produce the rest, it may skew the measurement. There is another version of show that accepts the max number of rows to show, which may lead to more accurate results, if the parameter is set close to the actual number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you are running the below SQL as SPARK SQL and the sQL takes few minutes to execute on huge volume of data.

"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE <>;"

Now, one of the ways could be initialize a dataframe with this SQL and create a view out of it.

```
val dbDf6 = spark.sql("select * from table_name where <filter> = 'Y'");
//When the above statement is executed then DAG will be created but execution will 
not happen.
//Note time before triggering execution (pro grammatically or otherwise)
dbDf6.count();
//Note time after triggering execution (pro grammatically or otherwise)
```